# How to short alphabetic manually in Ruby? without sort or sort_by method

Tags: ruby, sorting

How `sort` or `sort_by` methods work in Ruby when sorting alphabetic array?
How do it manually without use build in method `sort` or `sort_by`?

example:

```
irb(main):036:0> array = ['a','e','b','d','c']
=> ["a", "e", "b", "d", "c"]
irb(main):037:0> array.sort
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: You can get ascii code of each char like that `'a'.ord => 97`. The higher the number the deeper char in alphabet. So your task becomes to sort an array of integers and there are lots of examples how to do it manually. Here is [`ascii table`](https://www.asciitable.com/) for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicate elements:

```
arr = ['a','e','b','d','c']

('a'..'z').to_a & arr
  #> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

If there may be duplicate elements:

```
arr = ['a','e','c','b','d','e','c']

h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "e"=>2, "c"=>2, "b"=>1, "d"=>1} 
(('a'..'z').to_a & arr).flat_map { |s| [s]*h[s] }
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e"]
```

Notes:

- The doc [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-26) states, "The order is preserved from the original array".
- `('a'..'z').to_a & arr` is the same as `('a'..'z').to_a & arr.uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write your own algorithm?

```
def custom_sort(ary)
  start_ = []
  end_ = []
  loop do
    break if ary.size <= 1
    a, b = ary.min, ary.max
    start_ << ary.delete_at(ary.index(a))
    end_ << ary.delete_at(ary.index(b))
  end
  start_ << ary[0] unless ary.empty?
  start_ + end_.reverse
end

ary = ['a','e','b','d','c','a','a']
custom_sort(ary) #=> ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```